# WSO2 v5.9.0 SAMLS SSO with Service Provider (AD) 'user must change password at next logon' causes auth error instead of redirecting to .NET App

Tags: .net-core, wso2, single-sign-on, saml

Hi have not been able to find an answer on stackoverflow or online hoping someone has experience of a similar setup.

We have .NET Core 3.1 user management application which obtains user information from a Windows 2016 Active Directory server (application access is done via the groups defined in AD) fairly rudementary the idea is:

1. Start application > Redirect to WSO2 (version 5.9.0) IAM Logon page
2. Attemp to logon with a valid AD user (which has been set to 'user must change password at next logon'..)
3. WSO2 appears to attempt to authenticate and then logon however fails
4. Kibana shows logon failed message for this particualr user
5. The WSO2 logon page shows an error message

However what we were expecting to happen was for a redirect to occur back to the .NET Core application and we customised the logon.jsp related pages as per the WSO2 Customisation guide.

WSO2 does not have an identity providers it uses a service provider with SAML SSO configured.

The custom logon.jsp page has some code that checks the incoming RelyingParty value and performs the appropriate redirect as required.

**The issue:**

The redirect is not working as expected instead of redirecting back to the .NET Core application that made the initial call to the WSO2 IAM the above occurs i.e. the logon page shows an authentication error.

What we would like for the server to do is redirect back the .NET Core application IF the 'user must change password at next logon' radio button is enabled on their AD account - this needs to happen at the server side i.e. WSO2 (well that's my limited understanding if you know better please do advise).

**Ideal scenario:**

.NET App startup > WSO2 logon page

> SAML SSO flow > LDAP query to AD return user

> detect the 'user must change password at next logon' is true and then redirect back to the .NET app where the app will take over query AD display the change password views (nothing special about these standard change-password actions)

> .NET App > call WSO2 again perform valid logon return with SAML SSO response back to .NET APP.

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: Are you using the WSO2 IS product? If so please share the product version.

Comment: Saranki thanks missed that off we are on version 5.9.0

Answer (score 0):

As per your issue description, I believe that you have made the following configuration in the AD.
[image]

I believe you have initiated the **Admin Forced Password Reset flow** by setting the "**User must change password at next login**" option in the AD for the user. But unfortunately, it is not possible as once the "change password at next login" is selected in the AD, it marks the password as expired and the WSO2 IS treats it as Authentication Failed (LDAP error code 49). Therefore, it will require API level customization of WSO2 IS basic authenticator and the user store manager to achieve your requirement.

But in the WSO2 IS [Admin Forced Password Reset flow](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/forced-password-reset/), the user will be given an OTP through email to log in to the IS and the password reset flow will be initiated as similar to your requirement without using the AD. Hence, it is recommended to use the Admin Forced Password Reset flow available in the WSO2 IS to reset the password of the user.

Comment: Saranki thank you for the detailed reply very much appreciated. Unfortunately due to the setup here we are not using any of the admin features of WSO2 its purely aciting as an IdP and KM.